# Windows 10 Viewing photos by month & year

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have just upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 and wondered if anyone can help me with a query please ?

In Windows 7 I had all my photos of the grandchildren in one folder called 'Freddie & Anna' that was set up as follows:

```
Libraries/Pictures/My Photos/Freddie & Anna
```

- There were no sub folders for months/years within the 'Freddie & Anna' folder.
- When I clicked on the folder 'Freddie & Anna' the system displayed month & year 'icons' so that I could select the photos I wanted to view by clicking on the appropriate month & year 'icon'.
- If my memory is correct I did this by using 'Arrange by' within the 'Freddie & Anna' folder.

I have set up the following folder structure in Windows 10:

```
Libraries/Pictures/My Pictures/My Photos/Freddie & Anna
```

and all the photos of my grandchildren are in the folder 'Freddie & Anna'.

There are no sub folders for months/years within the 'Freddie & Anna' folder.

When I click on the folder 'Freddie & Anna' I want my system to do what it did in Windows 7 and display the month & year icons but it does what I don't want and displays all the photos and groups them under the headings 'Earlier This Week', 'Last Week', 'Earlier This Month', Earlier This Year', and 'A Long Time Ago'.  The system does this very slowly.

In Windows 7 the system was pretty quick to display the month & year 'icons' and then to display the appropriate photos if I clicked on one of the month & year 'icons'.

I would like to set up my folders/photos in Windows 10 so they are displayed as my system did in Windows 7.

Can anyone help me to do this please?

Comment: [WINDOWS 10- Has the option to arrange photos by month been removed?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-has-the-option-to-arrange-photos-by/030d3854-433d-433d-8a2e-126dc8dd5407?auth=1)

Comment: Thanks David, I have just read the thread you referred to and it has answered all my prayers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I view photos by month & year?

> Instead of going straight to your photos, you have to scroll down the
>   menu on the left hand side:
>
> [image]
>
> Open your photo folders through the libraries options/folders. After
>   that it works just like it did before:
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Source [WINDOWS 10- Has the option to arrange photos by month been removed?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-has-the-option-to-arrange-photos-by/030d3854-433d-433d-8a2e-126dc8dd5407?auth=1)